# how to change the color of a div element when an image is dragged onto it?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am uploading an image using an input tag and fileReader.
I have made the image draggable using drag and drop API of angular material. Also, there are 2 divs.
The following code shows it.

```
 <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" >
    <img  id="blah" [src]="url" alt="your image" cdkDrag/>


<div class="box1">
    hi
</div>

<div class="box2">
    hi
</div>
<div class="box3">
    hi
</div>
```

My requirement is that, when I drag the image into one of the div boxes, the color of the div should change. Right now I am able to drag the image into the div boxes but how do I change the color of the div when the image is dragged on to it.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this ?

Comment: i am unable to ..some tech issue with me

Comment: you has the event cdkDropListEntered, see:https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList. NOTE: for create a tackblitz simple https://stackblitz.com/ and create an Angular service, or, if you want not start in an empty project, in the examples of material you can edit an example and fork the example

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided, I have the following idea.

Steps:

1. check which parent node is the related div by using `document.querySelector('#blah').parentNode`
2. assign the related DOM to a variable as follow:`const divNeeded = document.querySelector('#blah').parentNode`
3. Suppose you have some color defined in your css file, let say it is called `relatedStyle`, you can add it to `divNeeded` by using `.classList.add('relatedStyle')`.

Example for the style in CSS file:

```
.relatedStyle{
 background-color: blue
}
```